# Why won't my Bootstrap 4 page row wrap when I use flex-flow plus grid system classes?

Tags: flexbox, grid, row, word-wrap, col

I have a sidebar for searching, and main content to the right of the sidebar.  I want the sidebar to remain approx the same width, while the main content can shrink horizontally when the browser window is shrinking horizontally.  I am using the Bootstrap 4 grid system to accomplish this.  In addition, I am using flex to enable row wrapping.  The grid system responsive width works ok, up until the browser shrinks to approx "col-6" size, upon which any further shrinking DOES NOT yield row wrap.  I want row wrap at the smallest width to accommodate small devices.  How can I achieve this (code below)?  I am very new at using bootstrap and flex in general.  I am a backend developer dipping my toes into responsive web design.  Please advise.

Also, please note that this is not about a "fixed sidebar", at least not yet, as that is instead a sidebar that is fixed during scrolling vertically.  I am interested in horizontal responsiveness.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="d-flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div id="search" class=" col-6 col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-xl-3">
        <h4 id="searchTitle">Search Criteria</h4>
        <div id="searchCriteria">
            a form goes here ...                
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="searchResultsColumn" class="col-6 col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9 col-xl-9">
        <h4 id="resultTitle">Search Results</h4>
        <div id="searchResultsRows">
            search results go here ...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When you say wrapped do you mean on col-6 id=search is stacked on top of id=searchResultsColumn ?

Comment: @Kilmazing, yes, that is the intent.  Much thanks for your answer.

Comment: Sorry,I am a newbie, and I do not understand why my question was downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I assume col-6 in a 12 grid system will yield 50% width. If you want the rows to wrap at a certain viewport why are you dividing the two elements into 12 evenly? At your desired break point give both a width of 100%, or whatever the appropriate bootstrap values are e.g.

```
<div id="search" class="col-12">
 ...
</div>
<div id="searchResultsColumn" class="col-12">
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: much thanks for it, I am a newbie and this helped me alot.